# Partitioning inputs in scanf

Tags: c

I want to accept the string and the float value in between the '@' is present. I have tried some what like this but it's not working; it is taking the whole input as the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[10000];
    float number;
    scanf("%s@%f",str,&number);    //input BMW@23.5 Expected output BMW 23.5
    printf("%s %f\n",str,number);  //actual output BMW@23.5 0.000000
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: thanks @xing you saved my time.its working fine

Comment: if my input is like this how to handle this BMW@12.34 AUDI@34.5.inbetween spaces.

Comment: @Rajkumar Also check the return value of `scanf()` before relying on the variables to have been assigned.

Comment: thanks @unwind now its working.thank you

Answer (score 1):

Get all as a `char[]` and parse it:

```
int main()
{
    char str[10000];
    float number;

    scanf("%s", str);
    char *at_pos = strrchr(str, '@');
    if (at_pos)
    {
        number = atof(at_pos + 1);
        // manage errors in number
        printf("%s %f\n", str, number);
    }
    else
    {
        // manage error
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that to get the desired output, you'd need to specify `%.1f` in the `printf` format string — trivia.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //using the "[^@]" can really save your time.
    //But you can do a lot in this approach of mine. Not just in that case.
    //Feel free to ignore this but if you want to check and understand the logic there, there's the code that i wrote. Then you can just improve it. Tnx.

    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {

        char str[10000];
        char c;//The idea is, collect the input 1 by 1.
        float f;
        float power = 10;
        int counter = 0;//We need this for the string.

        c = getchar();//get the first character
        str[counter] = c;//store it in the first element
        counter++;
        c = getchar();//Since we know that the input is string, we assume that there's a next character of course.

        while(c != '@')
        {
            //But what if the user didn't enter a '@' character?
            //Do this!
            if(c == 10)
            {
                printf("I can't find the '@' there. =)\n\n");
                return 0;
            }

            str[counter++] = c;    //Test the recently collected character if
            c = getchar();         //it's '@' or not. If not, then store it
        }                         //in the string and continue to collect the
                                 //next characters then store each of it in
                                 //the string again and again until it reaches the '@'. From there you stop.                     

        //after collecting all the characters, start collecting the numbers.

        c = getchar();//collect
        f = c - '0';//convert character to digit. I would bet you know this. Then store it in your float variable.
        c = getchar();//collect again

        //then test the recently collected again. Just like before

        while(c != 10 && c != '.')//10 is the ASCII of the <enter> or new line right?. //We will also stop if we encounter '.' (dot)..
        {
            //while if it's not 10 or dot, add it your float variable. But don't forget the rules. use the power of 10 to.

            f = f * 10 + (c - '0');

            c = getchar();//collect again.
        }

        //do this again
        c = getchar();
        f += (c - '0') / power;//now divide it with power
        c = getchar();
        power *= 10;//then increase the power.


        //Now collect the decimals

        while(c != 10)//just like before
        {
            f += (c - '0') / power;     //just do this over and
            power *= 10;                //over again until
            c = getchar();              //it reaches the ASCII 10.
        }

        //Test it if you got it. =)
        printf("%s @ %f", str, f);

        return 0;
    }








    //here's the clean code.
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {

        char str[1000];
        char c;
        float f;
        float power = 10;
        int counter = 0;

        c = getchar();
        str[counter] = c;
        counter++;
        c = getchar();

        while(c != '@')
        {
            //But what if the user didn't enter a '@' character?
            //Do this!
            if(c == 10)
            {
                printf("I can't find the '@' there. =)\n\n");
                return 0;
            }

            str[counter++] = c;
            c = getchar();
        }

        c = getchar();
        f = c - '0';
        c = getchar();

        while(c != 10 && c != '.')
        {
            f = f * 10 + (c - '0');
            c = getchar();
        }

        c = getchar();
        f += (c - '0') / power;
        c = getchar();
        power *= 10;

        while(c != 10)
        {
            f += (c - '0') / power;
            power *= 10;
            c = getchar();
        }

        printf("%s @ %f", str, f);

        return 0;
    }
```